# Составить регулярное выражение для правильной расстановки знаков препинания

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Задание такое:

> Исправьте строку в соответствии с правилом расстановки знаков препинания (точка, запятая, тире, точка с запятой, двоеточие, многоточие, круглые, квадратные и фигурные скобки): перед каждым знаком препинания (кроме тире и открывающихся скобок) пробел отсутствует, а после любого знака препинания (кроме открывающихся скобок) стоит ровно один пробел; в многоточии между точками пробелы отсутствуют.

Сделал тремя выражениями:

```
string = re.sub(r'\s*([:.,?})\]-])\s*', '\g<1>' + ' ', string)
string = re.sub(r'\s*\.\s*\.\s*\.\s*', '... ', string)
string = re.sub(r'\s*([{(\[])\s*', ' ' + '\g<1>', string)
```

Думаю, что это не самый оптимальный вариант, хотелось бы проще.

Comment: Одним врядли - правила разные для разных знаков

Comment: Можно несколькими выражениями. (если одним нельзя)

Comment: Можно. Показывайте, что не получилось

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/l0KKnA/1